# php Сортировка массива

Tags: php

Вообщем у меня есть прокт на yii2 там есть категории со связью многие ко многим, я написал виджет которыйх их выбирает и распологает как надо и мне надо отсортировать в алфавитном порядке все категории, я делаю это так:

```
protected function getTree () {
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($this->data as $id => &$node) {
        if ($node['category_id_1'] == 0) {
            $tree[$node['categoryId2']['id']] = &$node['categoryId2'];
        } else {
            $tree[$node['category_id_1']]['childs'][$node['categoryId2']['id']] = &$node['categoryId2'];
        }
    }

    uasort($tree, function ($a, $b) {
        $lower_a = mb_strtolower($a['name']);
        $lower_b = mb_strtolower($b['name']);

        if ($lower_a == $lower_b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($lower_a < $lower_b) ? -1 : 1;
    });
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tree); $i++) {
        if (!empty($tree[$i]['childs'])) {
            uasort($tree[$i]['childs'], function ($a, $b) {
                $lower_a = mb_strtolower($a['name']);
                $lower_b = mb_strtolower($b['name']);

                if ($lower_a == $lower_b) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return ($lower_a < $lower_b) ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Грубо говоря после того как я построил дерево категорий я его сортирую, но у меня сортеруется только родительские категории, дочернии почему-то не меняются. Нужна помощь.

Comment: а у вас в массиве `$tree` индексы идут подряд с 0? По идее, нет. Вам нужно заменить `for ($i = 0; $i < count($tree); $i++) {` на `foreach($tree as &$category){
    if (!empty($category['childs'])) {` ну и т.д.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов  Урааа работает, может это как ответ оформите, чтобы его отметить как правильный.

Comment: Да, сейчас пропробую)

Comment: а если при выборке данных их отсортировать, они  в вашем дереве не станут сортированными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как при формировании массива `$tree` индексы в нем идут не по порядку и с промежутками, нельзя использовать обычный цикл `for` с счетчиком. В данном случае подойдет `foreach`:

```
foreach($tree as &$category){
    if (!empty($category['childs'])) {
        uasort($category['childs'], function ($a, $b){
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```